# Relationship / difference between dreload() and autoreload

Tags: python, ipython

IPython offers something known as [deep_reload](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.lib.deepreload.html?highlight=dreload) which is also available as a [terminal option](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/options/terminal.html?highlight=dreload) that can be activated in `ipython_config.py`.

There is also the extension [auto_reload](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/autoreload.html?highlight=autoreload#module-IPython.extensions.autoreload) which could also be activated by default in `ipython_config`.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- deepreload: When I ask to deep-reload a, also reload b and c, which a imports, and d, which b imports (and so on).
- autoreload: Every time I run code, check to see if modules have changed since they were last loaded, and reload any that have changed. This also does some magic so that instances of reloaded classes get the code from the new classes.